# Correspondence of Exponential maps

Tags: differential-geometry, exponential-function, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I've been studying Differential geometry and in one lecture we talked about Lie groups and how the exponential map reduces to the matrix exponential map for matrix Lie groups.

We defined $\exp\vert_p(v)$ := $\gamma(1,p,v)$ where $\gamma(t,p,v)$ is the unique geodesic s.t.:
\begin{align}
\gamma(0,p,v) = p \\
 \gamma'(0,p,v) = v
\end{align}

On the other hand for $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ the exponential map was defined in the following way:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{exp}(At) := \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{At}{n!}
\end{align}

Since the matrix exponential map was responsible for giving the more general exponential its name the definition above better reduce to the matrix exponential on $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$.

Let the components of the matrices in $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ define a global chart.
I understand that $\operatorname{exp}(At)$ then defines a smooth curve on $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ for any $A \in \mathbb{R}^{nxn}$. But how can I also prove that the matrix exponential corresponds to $\gamma(t,\mathbb{1},A)$?

Comment: You have to but a bi-invariant metric on $GL_n(\Bbb R)$ to talk about its geodesics and Riemannian exponential map.

Comment: Indeed there's three things here called the exponential map which neatly coincide on a matrix Lie group with appropriate bi-invariant Riemannian metric. There's a matrix exponential map, there's the Riemannian exponential map and there's the Lie theoretic exponential map. The first you are familiar with, the second is defined in terms of geodesics and the third is defined in terms of one parameter subgroups (this is the smooth curve you mention)

Comment: Note that a bi-invariant Riemannian metric can only be found if the group is the product of compact and Abelian but a pseudo-Riemannian metric will work as well I think.